# how to continue numbers in pagination in php

Tags: php

```
  $tbl_name="info";  //your table name

   // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?

       $adjacents = 2;
```

/*

```
First get total number of rows in data table. 

If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.

     */

         $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";

          $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

         $total_pages = $total_pages[num];



        /* Setup vars for query. */

       $targetpage = "pagination.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)

           $limit = 2;         //how many items to show per page

        $page = $_GET['page'];

           if($page) 

          $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;    //first item to display on this page

         else

          $start = 0;        //if no page var is given, set start to 0



          /* Get data. */

        $sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";

         $result = mysql_query($sql);



          /* Setup page vars for display. */

          if ($page == 0) $page = 1;     //if no page var is given, default to 1.

         $prev = $page - 1;       //previous page is page - 1

    $next = $page + 1;       //next page is page + 1

      $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.

         $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;      //last page minus 1



        /* 

      Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 

        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.

      */



        $pagination = "";

     if($lastpage > 1)

   { 

            $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";

            //previous button

                if ($page > 1) 

           $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"> Previous <<</a>";

       else

            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"> Previous <<</span>"; 



         //pages 

       if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up

          { 

       for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)

      {

         if ($counter == $page)

     $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";

      else

        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     

       }

         }

       elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some

      {

          //close to beginning; only hide later pages

        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))  

       {

       for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)

             {

      if ($counter == $page)

       $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";

    else

     $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     

      }

      $pagination.= "...";

      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";

     $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  

          }

         //in middle; hide some front and some back

          elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))

         {

          $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";

           $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";

       $pagination.= "...";

   for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)

       {

         if ($counter == $page)

  $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";

       else

  $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     

      }

      $pagination.= "...";

  $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";

  $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  

     }

     //close to end; only hide early pages

    else

     {

        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";

       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";

       $pagination.= "...";

     for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)

           {

        if ($counter == $page)

           $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";

            else

              $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     

            }

         }

          }



            //next button

             if ($page < $counter - 1) 

          $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">Next >>  </a>";

          else

       $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Next >> </span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>\n";  

       }

      $query1="select * FROM info order by id desc LIMIT $start, $limit";

          $result1=mysql_query($query1);


       if($_GET['page']!='' )

     {

       $i=$start+1;

       }

          else

             {



         $i='1';

       }
         $k=1;

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {

           ?>

      <tr>
   <td>
   <?php echo $k++; ?></td>

       <td>
     <td>
         <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>

    <td>
      <?php echo $row["mobile_number"]; ?></td></td>
 </tr>
   <?php } ?>
     </table>
    <?php echo $pagination; ?>

     </body>
       </html>
```

this is my code for pagination in php...it showing 2 results on a page because the limit is 2 per page...but now the problem is that when i click on pagination to load another page...then it loads the second page with next two records but the number starts from 1 ....what i want is that when the first page shows two records it shows numbers 1 and 2 and when i click on second page then at that second page it should continue the numbers and show 3 -4 but not 1 and 2....can anyone help with this??

Comment: I advice you to stop using mysql-functions because they will be deprecated soon! Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: ok but is there any solution for this??

Comment: What is the URL when you place mouse on the pagination numbers (1,2,3...)?

Comment: wamp/pagination.php?page=1;...this comes on the url

Comment: It is not the URL, give me the full URL like http://localhost/pagination.php?page=2...  You can replace your server name.

Comment: localhost/practice/pagination.php?page=2   this is the url....practice is my folder's name

Comment: Can you prefix echo in your query like below `echo '<br />'.$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit"`;

Comment: i dont really get your point??

Comment: First of all, debugging a code without accessing is very difficult. I advised you to print your query on each page (when page is getting loaded after clicking on page number ) and check what query is getting executed. Its just a debugging process. You can share the query getting printed here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45992/discussion-between-user3181292-and-ursitesion)

Answer (score 0):

try this

$page_numbers = intval($total_pages['num']/$limit)+1;

then in for loop you can get all ur page numbers. and the passing ur page id and last id to pagination u can perform pagination completely

Comment: i have to write this line where exactly??

Comment: just replace ur statement $total_pages=$total_pages['num'] with this code and then on ur html get ur $page_numbers variable accessible in for loop to get correct number of pages and from ther u can pass the last id of page as well as row shown in data grid to run ur sql query with orderby $last_id,$limit accordingly

Comment: actualy when i replaced this line with yours...then the page is showing nothing...i think the problem is that $total_pages variable is used 3 - 4 times so when i replaced it then the code is not able to ind this variable and therefore showing error...should i  replace it everywhere ??

Comment: in that case u find the usage of ur variable and then replace . and please u haven't used limit in ur pagination

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = $("#start").val();
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = $("#count").val();

$.post("paginate.php",{start:start,count:count},function(get_page){
$("#newpage").load(get_page);
start += 10
})
});
```

make a text field with a display:none put there the value of per page make sure the id is equal to start and value is equal to per page make another text field and name it count, still display hidden value of 10

for the paginate.php

```
mysql_connect(username and password and host)
mysql_select_db(database name);
$start = $_POST['start'];
$count = $_POST['count'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE yourclause='clause' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start , $count ")
```